# Write array to the plist file of my project directory

Tags: objective-c, plist

Here is the code I tried to write some string values to my database.plist file in the same folder of my project. Therefore I can't use NSDocumentDirectory. This code didn't give me any error. But String value doesn't save in my plist file array.

```
  -(void)dataFetching
{
NSMutableDictionary *categoryList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"database.plist"];
NSMutableArray *array =(NSMutableArray *) [categoryList valueForKey:@"Saved"];

NSString *testStr = @"test String";

int lastItemIndex = [array count];
[array insertObject:testStr atIndex:lastItemIndex];

[categoryList writeToFile:@"database.plist" atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: you cannot change any file in the project folder; use the `Documents` folder instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the issue is you are not writing an array. And also make sure that before writing to plist your data format should be proper. So try like this:-

```
[array writeToFile:@"database.plist" atomically:YES];
```